# Plotting changes in Patch variables?

Tags: plot, netlogo

I am trying to model my agents effects on their patch landscape, ie harvesting grain over a period of time. I have a variable that patches-own `penergy`, I would like to plot the total `penergy` across the behaviorspace over time. I have an idea how to do this but I don't think I am doing it the most effective way.

To complicate matters, I have multiple grain types, ie `ptype`. I would like to plot these types independently.

```
to patch-health
 if ptype = 1[
  let new-penergy min(list 10 (penergy))
   let diff (new-penergy - penergy)
   set Wheat-health ((sum ptype1-health) + diff)
 ]
 if ptype = 0 [
  let new-penergy min(list 10 (penergy))
  let diff (new-penergy - penergy)
  set Barley-health ((sum ptype0-health) + diff)
  ]
end

to-report ptype1-health
 if ptype = 1 [
 report [penergy] of patches
 ]
end

to-report ptype0-health
  if ptype = 0 [
    report [penergy] of patches
  ]
end
```

It produces a list of each patches `penergy` but I added the `sum pytpe0-health` function to convert the list to a total `penergy`. The plot works but the model is bogged down and running very slow.

I want think this is easy but can't seem to figure it out. Is there a more efficient way to achieve similar results?

Comment: Can you include more code? I have some questions that would probably be sorted by seeing a little more of your program. Where is `patch-health` called? Where is `penergy` updated? What do your plot update commands look like? Check out the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines for tips on formatting your question with a minimal complete example. Without more detail, I would try a pen update command of `plot sum [penergy] of patches` in your plot.